# How to get json element's property from Entire Json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My json value  looks like this:

```
[{"Id":"1169"},{"Id":"1164"},{"Id":"1163"},{"Id":"1162"},{"Id":"1161"}]
```

Now i want to store only numeric values 1169,1164,1163,1162,1161 into different array.How can i do this?

Comment: Decode this json and iterate the resulting array and fetch the numeric values and store them in different array.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar : decoded it but how can i fetch numeric values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
    $values = array_values(json_decode($json,true));
```

Comment: when i am trying to print $values as error_log($values); then it gives error like: error_log() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: @FastTrack yes because `$values` because am array ... you need to use `error_log(json_encode($values))` if you want to save it to error log

Comment: Ok,now i want to fetch numeric value into another array. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

its not array its a json.

You can change from array to json and json to array.

```
$a = json_encode($yourArray);
```

AND

```
$b= json_decode($yourJson);
```